# Proper Way to Convert Byte Array to Float? (Arduino)

Tags: c++, arduino, floating-point, byte

I'm attempting to convert an array of 4 `byte` values to a single `float` value in Arduino.

I'm using a `union` in order to store my values, and I'm able to convert a `long` to a `float` that way.

Here's the code:

```
union value {
  float f;
  unsigned long l;
  byte b[4];
} value;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Setting 105.00 to the value variable via modifying the field "l"
  value.l = 0x42D20000;
  Serial.println("\nFloat value: " + String(value.f));
  Serial.print("Byte values: {");

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
  {
    Serial.print(value.b[i], HEX);
    Serial.print(", ");
  }
  
  Serial.println("}");
  
  // Setting 4.55 to the value variable via modifying the field "b"
  value.b[0] = 0X40;
  value.b[1] = 0X91;
  value.b[2] = 0X99;
  value.b[3] = 0X9A;
  
  Serial.println("Float value: " + String(value.f));
  Serial.print("Byte values: {");

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
  {
    Serial.print(value.b[i], HEX);
    Serial.print(", ");
  }

  Serial.println("}");
}

void loop()
{
}
```

I first try to assing the value of 105 to the `l` field, and then read the `f` field. That appears to be successful, and I get the desired 105.00 in the `f` field if I try to read from it.

However, I subsequently want to assign a value of 4.55 to my `f` field by assigning each byte entry in the `b` array field. That does not appear to work, and I am left with a value of -0.00 in the `f` field if I try to read from it.

This is current output of the code shown above:

```
Float value: 105.00
Byte values: {0, 0, D2, 42, }
Float value: -0.00
Byte values: {40, 91, 99, 9A, }
```

While the individual bytes are saved successfully in the `b` field, the `f` field does not appear to update automatically.

Any ideas as to why I'm not able to get 4.55 as my `f` field in the latter half of the code above?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: You could have figured this out for yourself if you had assigned 4.55 to `f` and then printed out `b`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CPU is probably little-endian, which means the least-significant byte is stored at the beginning.

Have you tried this:

```
value.b[3] = 0X40;
value.b[2] = 0X91;
value.b[1] = 0X99;
value.b[0] = 0X9A;
```

Comment: Weird, I would have swapped the order of the bytes, not the order of the indices. But anyway clearly the right answer.

Comment: Whatever floats your boat; the assignments are clearly independent so you can reorder them however you want. The advantage of the current ordering is that it's easy to see that the assignment is equivalent to `value.l = 0x4091999a`.